# Laravel 5 Auth Logout not destroying session

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel5 Auth system for my new project, I am able to use registration and login functions with out any problem but logout is not working as expected, however I get redirected to url specified at `$redirectAfterLogout` but it does not destroy session so even after hitting logout button I am able to see dashboard.

Does laravel has some bug in Auth system, please suggest, thanks

Comment: how do you know the session is destroyed or not? Did you restrict the routes with auth?

Comment: @sgt After i click logout link, i am not able to visit `/auth/login`, it simply redirects me to dashboard.

Comment: I was having the same issue, my mistake was put the middleware "guest" to the logout route. :/

Maybe you are having the same problem.

Answer (score 28):

You have not provided any piece of code that you have used. However, the following code works:

```
public function getLogout(){
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

The `Session::flush();`clears all the existing sessions.

Comment: I am currently using Laravel 5 builting auth mechanism

Comment: So I hope you are able to destroy the session now?

Comment: I was having the same issue, my mistake was put the middleware "guest" to the logout route. :/

Maybe you are having the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Using Laravel 5.2, I registered a listener, handled the logout event and called Session::flush as suggested above. Seemed to work pretty well. Hope this is helpful.

EventServiceProvider.php

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\ClearSessionAfterUserLogout'
    ],
];
```

ClearSessionAfterUserLogout.php

```
public function handle(Logout $event)
{
    Session::flush();
}
```

Comment: I was having the same issue, my mistake was put the middleware "guest" to the logout route. :/

Maybe you are having the same problem.

Comment: Non static method 'flush' should not be called statically.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I tried everything, but in the end I could fix it.

My problem was that when I hit on the logout button, before that I had some http requests that weren't answered yet, so even when the user was log out, later with the response of the pending requests it got logged in again. Here is an example:

```
Another Request |   ***********************************
Logout Request  |          ********************
                |
Time            | --|------|-------------------|------|------>
                   t1      t2                  t3     t4
```

So Removing those non-answered requests worked for me. I hope that this answer helps :)

Comment: Where to remove those non-answered requests?

Comment: In my case I found those requests in some JQuery ajax calls, so I just removed that code, and then the log out started to work as expected. Hope I can help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

### It seems that in the

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

The `function getLogout()` is never reached, hence the `logout()` method never fires.

### In my case, in my

```
/app/Http/routes.php
```

### Iinstead of this:

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

### I changed it to:

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Comment: This solution is for Laravel 5.2.29 by the way.  Maybe the versions have slight revisions behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

By accepting the request object in a controller action (Remember to add this after the controller namespace declaration: **use Auth;** ):

```
 /**
 *
 * Render page
 *
 * @route POST /user/{user_id}/logout
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched to the database session driver and used the following code in my logout action

```
$request->session()->getHandler()->destroy($request->session()->getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

trait AuthenticatesUsers

```
public function logout(Request $request)
```

change this

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

to  this

```
$request->session()->regenerate(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are not probably reaching the logout() method. If you are using Laravel 5 builting auth mechanism then you will run AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait getLogout() method which does `$this->auth->logout();`

Find this code edit the method like below for debugging. If you see the string "Logging out" then you must be logged out. Ohterwise something is wrong with your routing and logout is just never executed.

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getLogout()
{
    dd("Logging out");
    $this->auth->logout();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Yes i am seeing "logging out" at screen after click logout link, that means logout link is hitting this function.

Comment: Other option could be that you have remembered your account. Please check user login status before and after logout() call.  You can use dd($this->auth->user()); for this. This will show you for sure if the user was logged in or not after logout

Comment: just tried this test, getting empty at after call, so that mean its destroying `auth->user()` but why login page is redirecting to dashboard even after logout.

Comment: At some point in the future user must have been logged back in. You need to check your controller getLogin() method and find out where exactly

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this, and I've come to a solution.

In short: The Laravel session reads and writes with middleware. It reads the stored session in at the start of the request, and writes any changes at the end of the request. If you make a redirect, then the current request never finishes, and the middleware write doesn't happen.

So, how to fix this? Depending on your implementation... you should `return` the redirect command rather than calling it directly.

```
return redirect($redirectAfterLogout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and it turned out using the 'file' driver for sessions somehow the server was creating files it could not modify later but there was no file permission warning. I switched to a redis implementation so I unfortunately can not say how to fix the file creation issue, but thought this might save someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the logout method in AuthController.php

Here is code sample:

```
public function logout(){
        Session::flush();
        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();
        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth()->logout();
```

For the newest versions.

Comment: Still required as of now, I think it's about whether you are allowing the logout request to fully execute before expecting the user to be fully logged out.