# Laravel 5 logout or session destroy

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issues logging out of a laravel 5.1 app - I believe the issue is that the session is not destroyed.

My question is nearly identical to:

[Laravel 5 Auth Logout not destroying session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621965/laravel-5-auth-logout-not-destroying-session)

with the caveat that my solution is to use

```
session_unset();
```

rather than

```
Session::flush();
```

so my working solution to logging out of a laravel 5.1 app is:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    \Auth::logout();
    session_unset();
    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');

    //these attempts will not remove values from the session.....

    //session()->forget('db');
    //\Session::flush();


}
```

any ideas why `\Session::flush();` and `session()->forget('db');` are not working?

Answer (score 10):

Could you try this:

```
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
```

If It's not working, check `"'driver' => 'file'"` or `"'domain' => null"` sections in Config->Session.php.

Comment: Session::flush(); does not work. session_unset(); does work. Driver is set to file, domain is set to null. I am wondering if it is my development environment, which brings me to setting up a different development environment.

Comment: I will try to help you at this Saturday via Skype. Could you add me on skype: alierdemsunar.

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code

```
Auth::logout();
```

or

```
session_unset();
```

or

```
Session::flush();
```

Comment: What does this answer add? that's exactly what the op did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/login');
 }
```

Comment: Another answer which brings nothing, because that's all in the code of the question